# What is happening with the descriptors in this class?

Tags: python, descriptor

I completed a practice problem in which you build a class, Temperature(), which accepts a temperature in celsius, kelvin, or Fahrenheit, and can return the converted values of the other scale.  I did this using descriptors, and it was my first time being exposed to them.  I wound up with a correct answer after a lot of searching and basically finding a similar class online which I modified.  The thing is, I still can't really wrap my head around what is happening when the class is implemented.  I read the documentation on descriptors and watched some videos on MRO and managed attributes, and I'm still not able to fully understand what's going on.

```
class Celsius():
    def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val=val
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.val
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.val=value

class Fahrenheit():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.celsius * 1.8 + 32
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.celsius=(value-32)/1.8

class Kelvin():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return (instance.celsius + 273.15)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.celsius = (value - 273.15)


class Temperature():
    celsius = Celsius()
    fahrenheit = Fahrenheit()
    kelvin = Kelvin()
```

I'm particularly not understanding how something like

```
t1=Temperature()
t1.kelvin=50
```

is executed.  When I set the kelvin attribute to 50, that calls the `__set__` method of Kelvin() correct? I don't understand where that value of 50 is then stored in this case.  And I also don't understand how `instance.celsius = (value - 273.15)` in the `__set__` is treated when I assign `t1.kelvin=50`.  I am not understanding something very fundamental here but I'm a bit stuck after doing some reading.

Comment: Nothing to do with the MRO here - you don't have a hierarchy of subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

First: this has to do with "descriptions" and not "method resolution order" which is an expression reserved for searching methods and attributes on super-classes.

Then, for your specific doubts:

> When I set the kelvin attribute to 50, that calls the `__set__` method
> of Kelvin() correct?  I don't understand where that value of 50 is
> then stored in this case.

Yes, the method is called. The value "50" proper *is not* stored in this case. In this design the `Temperature` instance has to offer a single, valid temperature measure, which can be kept consistent and be written and read back regardless of the desired scale. The scale choosen for the internal representation of this value is Celsius (although the Celcius descriptor as shown in the question is incorrect, see more bellow). So, both reads and writes in Kelvin and Fahrenheit *do not* store their values: writtings convert the scale to Celsius, and set the Celsius value, and reads, through the `__get__` method retrieve the Celsius value and convert it back to the desired scale. In other words: the values for Kelvin and F. are "computed".

> And I also don't understand how instance.celsius = (value - 273.15) in
> the **set** is treated when I assign t1.kelvin=50.

It is treated the same way any other assignemtn to a temperature instance "celsius" is done: the code in  `Celsius.set` is run - and the value it gets, in this case, is the initial value passed to "instance.kelvin" minus 273.15: the expression (value - 273.15) has nothing special about it (and the parenthesis are actually not needed there). It covnerts the passed value to celsius. The fact that  `instance.celsius` points to a descriptor make the **=** operator behave differently: the `__set__` method in Celsius is called - and receives the result of the minus operation (which happens to be the proper value in celsius)

**Wrong code**: now, pay attention to one thing: descriptors are instantiated in the class body - and are shared for all instances of that class. This means that all instances of `Temperature` are sharing the *same* instance of your `Celsius` class: so it must not hold its value as an attribute of "self". If you create two instances of `Temperature` in your code as is, you will see they are not independent, as both reads and writes to all scales are performed in the `val` attribute of `Temperature.celsius`.
The correct thing to do is to keep the value in the *instance* argument received in the `__get__`  and `__set__` methods of descriptors.
To avoid recursion, that is tipically done by keeping a different attribute name on the instance - this can be done by adding a "_" prefix.

In this case, the `celsius` descriptor is just a "no operation" and could not even exist. Also, since you are writting a descriptor, if it would hardcode the internal attribute to be "_celsius", as in this example, more than one instance of the descriptor in the same class would interfere with the other: one has to use a dynamic name for the descriptor.

```
class Celsius():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        # The name could be set automatically
        # by having a __set_name__ method, but let's
        # go one step at a time
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance: 
            #when retrieved from the class, "instance" is None, then
            # return the descriptor itself,
            # and do not attempt to fetch values
            return self
        return getattr(instance, "_" + self.name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        setattr(instance, "_" + self.name)
```

Other than that, I suggest you add "print" calls inside your getters and setters and try it until you grasp the flow of what you are asking here:

```
class Celsius():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        # The name could be set automatically
        # by having a __set_name__ method, but let's
        # go one step at a time
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance:
            return self
        print(f"celsius getter, picking the internal value from '_{self.name}'")
        return getattr(instance, "_" + self.name)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(...)
        setattr(instance, "_" + self.name)
class Fahrenheit():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance: 
            return self
        print(...)
        return instance.celsius * 1.8 + 32
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(...)
        instance.celsius=(value-32)/1.8

class Kelvin():
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if not instance: 
            return self
        print(...)
        return (instance.celsius + 273.15)
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print(...)
        instance.celsius = (value - 273.15)


class Temperature():
    celsius = Celsius("celsius")
    fahrenheit = Fahrenheit()
    kelvin = Kelvin()
```

And finally: keep in mind that for code that is not reusable, and fit for a single attribute, like in this example, Python already offers `property` which is a descriptor, but already filled up so that you can just worry about the logic in the getter and setter, and do not worry about dealing with the descriptor instance itself: your methods already get a reference to the instance in "self".

Comment: I really appreciate the extensive answer.  I see that I'm much farther away from understanding this than I initially thought.  I'll have to reread what you wrote quite a few times I think haha.  Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: fix yor odcde as I indicated, and fill in the "print" calls, that should help.

Comment: So I made an attempt to implement the `__set_name__` method like you suggested after reading the documentation.  Would you say this is an improvement?

https://pastebin.com/LPiKAci7

When I check the `vars()` for multiple instances, each instance contains the data as private attributes.  This would solve the issue you mentioned, correct?

Comment: Yes - both things are improvement. Keeping the values in each instance is much more important, of course. `__set_name__` is a nice to have, it mostly allows you to not need passing in the name of the descriptor explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

`t1.kelvin = 50` is equivalent to

```
Temperature.kelvin.__set__(t1, 50)
```

The assignment does not immediately create or modify an instance attribute named `kelvin`; first, the type of `t1` is checked for a descriptor named `kelvin`, and when found, that descriptor's `__set__` method is called instead.

As a result, you can see that it's `t1.celsius = 50 - 273.15` that gets assigned.

`50` itself isn't stored anywhere. If you subsequently try something like

```
print(t1.kelvin)
```

the resulting call is `Temperature.kelvin.__get__(t1, Temperature)`, which returns `t1.celsius + 273.15`, effectively undoing the subtraction that set the value of `t1.celsius` in the first place.

In other words, all three descriptors "cooperate" by normalizing their particular value to degrees Celsius when set, and converting the Celsius temperature back to the desired scale when retrieved.

Comment: This is very helpful.  I didn't understand that kelvin is initially obtained by getting Celsius first.  It makes sense when you lay it out like that.  Between this and the code given by jsbueno with the print statements in it, I think I should be able to work out how things are happening.  Much appreciated.